# Javascript syntax for passing PHP variables

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, syntax

HELLO EVERYONE :D

I am having some diffculties passing php varaibles through javascript.

Basically this is the statement:

```
new Ajax.Updater( 'result', 'update_request.php?status='+status_change);
```

and I need to pass another variable after status_change, the variable I need to pass is the id of the ticket that is being updated.

So I tried this:

```
new Ajax.Updater( 'result', 'update_request.php?status='+status_change'&requestid='+request_id);
```

However this gives me an error stated below:

> Webpage error details
>
> Message: Expected ')' Line: 128 Char:
>   77 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://site_url/dev/time_off_new/main.php

I have tried double quotes, as well as a combination. I do not know why it is giving me such harrassment.

I ran the php script that it is attached to, and everything is working fine. After debugging I have narrowed it down to this statement, so everthing else is working fine.

Thank you ahead of time.

Peace and love!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a concatenation operator after the variable status_change

Try this

```
new Ajax.Updater( 'result', 'update_request.php?status='+status_change+'&requestid='+request_id);
```